# Creating Azure API Management using deleted name results in name "already in use" error

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I previously created and subsequently deleted an Azure API Management service using Terraform. It disappeared in Azure Portal. A few hours after that, when I tried to recreate API Management with the same name, I got  this error in the Azure Portal :
`"name already in use. Please select a different name."`
Also got similar error in Terraform as well.

Anyone knows why the name cannot be reused even though I am no longer seeing that name in my resource group?

Comment: APIM names need to be globally unique, not just within your resource group, since it is used when creating your endpoint URL. I'm assuming someone else has used your endpoint name after you deleted it.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your [APIM service have been soft deleted or not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/soft-delete). If the resource has been soft-deleted, and you want to create a new one with the same name,what you need to do is purge the resource and then recreate.

Get a soft-deleted instance by name:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/locations/{location}/deletedservices/{serviceName}?api-version=2020-06-01-preview
```

List all soft-deleted instances for a given subscription:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/deletedservices?api-version=2020-06-01-preview
```

Recover a deleted APIM instance:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{apimServiceName}?api-version=2020-06-01-preview
```

Purge a soft-deleted APIM instance:

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/locations/{location}/deletedservices/{serviceName}?api-version=2020-06-01-preview
```

Comment: how to generate oauth2 token for this api

Comment: Please have a look at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn645543(v=azure.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article with some PowerShell code (function) that wraps the REST calls, so you can just call the function with a few parameters like below.

Purge-ApiManagementInstance -SubscriptionId $subId -Location $location -Name $apimInstanceName

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/purging-azure-api-management-instance-james-hughes/

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, your instance has been soft deleted.
You need terraform to purge the instance on destroy, this is done by adding some config options on provider section
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/features-block#api_management

```
provider "azurerm" {
  api_management {
      # does not seem to work, insufficient rights?
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy         = true
      # as of now next attribute exists only on docs, never worked for me
      # https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/features-block#api_management
      #recover_soft_deleted_api_management = false
  }
----
}
```

According to terraform docs your SP also needs to have `recover` permission.

You can also use `az rest` to delete it

```
az rest --method delete --header "Accept=application/json" -u 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/123-123-123/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/locations/[eastus]/deletedservices/cloud-devops-test?api-version=2020-06-01-preview'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use AZ CLI for that now:

```
az apim deletedservice purge --help
```

example:

```
az apim deletedservice purge -l APIM_LOCALTION -n APIM_NAME
```