# How Do I Purge A Soft-Deleted APIM With Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management

Azure API Management is now "soft-deleted" to enable you to restore it if it was deleted by mistake.

[Creating Azure API Management using deleted name results in name "already in use" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349024/creating-azure-api-management-using-deleted-name-results-in-name-already-in-use)

When using `terraform destroy` it does the soft-delete, which makes it tricky with development as you often want to recreate it.

How can I purge the soft-deleted APIM with terraform?

Answer (score 5):

Ran into same thing, my quick research on how to call this API:

```
az rest --method delete --header "Accept=application/json" -u 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/locations/{eastus}/deletedservices/{api name}?api-version=2020-06-01-preview'
```

Comment: This is really useful for CI

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been incorporated in azurerm provider [v2.77.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases/tag/v2.77.0)

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time you can only do that through API call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2020-06-01-preview/deletedservices/purge

Answer (score 1):

The way to achieve this by using setting `purge_soft_delete_on_destroy` to true. This is done on the provider level:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    api_management {
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy = true
    }
  }
}
```

The [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69409576/1198379) led me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can call api to check and delete the soft deleted azure apims. scripts below.

Reference:- https://www.sharepointcollabs.com/2021/08/purging-soft-deleted-azure-apim-api.html

**#GET Request- To list all soft deleted apims in a specific subscription**

```
$token = Get-AzAccessToken

$request = @{

Method = 'GET'

Uri    = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/deletedservices?api-version=2020-06-01-preview"

Headers = @{

    Authorization = "Bearer $($token.Token)"

 }

}
```

Invoke-RestMethod @request  -OutFile c:\apimoutput.txt

**#DELETE Request- This will purge the soft deleted apim**

```
$token = Get-AzAccessToken

$request = @{

Method = 'DELETE'

Uri  = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/locations/{Location}/deletedservices/{APIMName}?api-version=2020-06-01-preview"

Headers = @{

    Authorization = "Bearer $($token.Token)"

 }

}
```

Invoke-RestMethod @request